# python yaml print key values only

Tags: python, dictionary, yaml

I would like to print from the following yaml file just the value of a

```
1w:
    team1:
      contact: team1@email.com
2w:
    team2:
      contact: team2@email.com
```

So far I have the following working:

```
    #!/usr/bin/env python

import yaml


def yaml_loader(filepath):
    with open(filepath, 'r') as file_descriptor:
#add condition to validate yaml
        data = yaml.load(file_descriptor)
    return data

def yaml_dump(filepath, data):
    with open(filepath, w) as file_descriptor:
        yaml.dump(data, file_descriptor)


if __name__ == "__main__":
    filepath = "log/log_registration.yaml"
    data = yaml_loader(filepath)

    items = data.get('3w')
    for item_roletype, value in items.iteritems():
        print value
```

Just edited my post because I realized that my yaml should have a different layout to avoid multiple entries overwrites.

At this point I am not sure how to print just the name of "team1" and "team2" and others that will follow. without the contact information.

The code above will not work at this moment ...

Comment: fyi it should be `open(filepath, 'w')`, not `open(filepath, w)`.

Answer (score 1):

## Edited since you edited the question

New yaml data

```
1w:
    team1:
        contact: team1@email.com
2w:
    team2:
        contact: team2@email.com
```

ok so with `data = yaml_loader(filepath)` we can look at `data`:

```
{'1w': {'team1': {'contact': 'team1@email.com'}},
 '2w': {'team2': {'contact': 'team2@email.com'}}}
```

and we can extract the data like this

```
for week, teams in data.items():
    for team in teams.keys():
        print('{}: {}'.format(key, team))
```

outputs:

```
1w: team1
2w: team2
```

---

Original answer: I think you've somewhat over complicated things

data:

```
1w:
    a: team1
    b: team1@email.com
2w:
    a: team2
    b: team2@email.com
```

code:

```
data = yaml_loader(filepath)
for key, value in data.items():
    print('{}[a] = {}'.format(key, value['a']))
```

outputs (with your data)

```
1w[a] = team1
2w[a] = team2
```

Answer (score 0):

```
if __name__ == "__main__":
    filepath = "log/log_registration.yaml"
    data = yaml_loader(filepath)

    for _, value in data.iteritems():
        for key, _ in value.iteritems():
            print(key)
```

Comment: I had to rewrite the layout because the yaml layout was wrongly created, not supporting more entries in 1w: or 2w:

Comment: Thanks @nikos It really worked. btw what does the "_" represent ?

Comment: is usually states that you won't need this variable in the future.

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure what output you are looking for.
There is no key like '3w' in your yaml file

If desired output is like this:

a: team2

b: team2@email.com

Then your code snippet should be like:

```
items = data.get('2w')
for item_roletype, value in items.iteritems():
    print "%s: %s" % (item_roletype, value)
```

Comment: I rewrote the question because I noticed that the layout of the yaml was wrong because if there would have been more entries in 1w: than only the last one would be printed not both